# How to find out the Object Type in a Salesforce Polymorphic relationship using the CData Salesforce Driver

Tags: salesforce, soql, cdata-drivers

Occasionally Salesforce Object have polymorphic relationships with other Salesforce Objects. In a polymorphic relationship, the referenced object of the relationship can be one of several different types of object. These polymorphic relationships are defined using polymorphic fields contained in a Salesforce Object. A polymorphic field is one where the related object might be one of several different types of objects. For example, the Who relationship field of a Task Object can be a Contact or a Lead. Similarly the What relationship field of a Task can be any non-Person Object in Salesforce.

How do I find out the Object Type of a Object ID in Polymorphic field using the CData Salesforce Driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce has "[Polymorphic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm)" for these. And looks like [CDATA supports it](http://cdn.cdata.com/help/RFC/jdbc/pg_sfjoin.htm).

```
SELECT Task.Subject, Contact.Name
FROM Task, Contact
WHERE Contact.Type='Contact'

SELECT Id, TYPEOF What 
        WHEN Account THEN Phone 
        WHEN Opportunity THEN Amount 
    END 
FROM Event
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But this looks like you have to JOIN to the right table. But in the case of most polymorphic fields e.g. WHAT_ID in Task, I do not know which table to JOIN to to. It could be any of non-people SFDC Objects. I need a way to figure out which Object a WHAT_ID references before I can join it.

Comment: 1st one yes, it's not a valid soql so might be cdata join. 2nd one is soql though. Can you `select what.type from task`? Worst case you can get the table name based on the WhatId value. All SF account records start with "001", contacts with "003". `select keyprefix from entitydefinition`?